# Which Event Intercepts When a Textbox Changes Value Via Access VBA Code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm changing the values of some textboxes of an Access form automatically. their control sources are as follows:

```
=SeImed(LucroBrutoOperacoes([txt_VendaValor];[txt_CompraValor])>=0;LucroBrutoOperacoes([txt_VendaValor];[txt_CompraValor]);Nulo)
```

so, when the related fields in the if clause "SeImed" (Iif, in english), a text field changes its value to the calculated value or to null ("Nulo"), as shown in the formula. this is working pretty fine. what I need is to intercept when this change happens, which cannot be done by Change or AfterUpdate or Dirty events, for instance. I tried them all, unsuccessfully. if any of you know how to intercept this value change, please, help me. I'd appreciate your help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That doesn't look like VBA code. What are those semicolons for, and where are the localized function names and keywords coming from? Also, something seems badly off with the parenthesis matching, since the IIf/SeImed call only has two parameters, not three.

Comment: Nathan, this is an internal function, found in the design mode of a textbox, in the expression bulider. IIf is an internal function (in my portuguese version is SeImed) and it has 3 parameters: condition, if true, if false.

Comment: LucroBrutoOperacoes is a function that I built in the general module class. but this is working fine. I just need to intercept changes when it occurs automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox will be recalculated whenever txt_VendaValor or txt_CompraValor changes.

So you can detect the change by watching for it in these places:

```
   txt_VendaValor_Change
   txt_VendaValor_AfterUpdate
   txt_CompraValor_Change
   txt_CompraValor_AfterUpdate
```

Note that events will sometimes fire even if the value hasn't actually changed, such as by entering "0" into a textbox that currently shows "0.0". If it is important to you to avoid false alarms, then you need to keep a copy of the last-known value of your calculated textbox. When an event fires, compare the last-known value to the current value to see if a change has really occurred.